# assignment to expression with array type error in c

Tags: c

[image]

I am getting this error as shown in the image pls tell me how to fix it.
the error is in line 115 of the code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#define MAX 100 
#define product_limit 50

typedef struct {
        int p_id;
        char p_name[product_limit + 1];
        int p_quantity; 
        int unit_price; 
        char type_product[50]; 
} product;
int main() 
 { 
        int ok = 1, menu;
        do 
            {
            menu = display_menu();
            if(menu < 1 || menu > 7) 
             {
            printf("Invaid option.\n");
             } 
            else 
                 {
           switch(menu)
                 {
            case 1:
            add_product();
            break;
            case 2:
            change_product();
            break;
            case 3:
            display_all_products();
            break;
        }
        }
        } 
        while(ok);
        printf("Exiting Program.\n");
        return 0;
}
int display_menu()
 {
        int menu;
        printf("Choose option from below.\n");
        printf("1. Add new product.\n");
        printf("2. Update product.\n");
        printf("3. Display products.\n");
        printf(". Exit.\n");
        scanf("%d", &menu);
        return menu;
}
product products[MAX];
int c_p = 0;
int product_exists(int id)
 {
        int x;
        for(x=0;x<c_p;x++) 
    {
        if(products[x].p_id == id) 
    {
        return x;
    }
    }
        return -1; 
}
int add_product() 
{
        int price,id,quantity,type;
        char name[product_limit + 1];
        printf("Product ID: ");
        scanf("%d", &id);
        if(product_exists(id) != -1) 
        {
            printf("ID: %d already exists.\n", id);
            return;
        }
        printf("Enter Product Name: ");
        scanf("%s", name);
        printf("Enter Quantity: ");
        scanf("%d", &quantity);
        printf("Enter Price: ");
        scanf("%d", &price);
        printf("Enter Product Type:");
        scanf("%s",type);
        products[c_p].p_id = id;
        strcpy(products[c_p].p_name, name);
        products[c_p].p_quantity = quantity;

        products[c_p].unit_price = price;
        c_p++;
        printf("Product added Successfully\n");
}
int change_product() 
{
        int id, exists,name;
        char z[2];
        printf("Product ID: ");
        scanf("%d", &id);
        exists = change_product(id);
        if(exists == -1) {
        printf("ID: %d not exists.\n", id);
        printf("Type Y to try once more or N back to menu: ");
        scanf("%s", z);
        if(strcmp(z, "Y") == 0) 
        {
        change_product();
        }
        } else {
            printf("Product found successfully\n");
            printf("Product Name: %s\n", products[exists].p_name);
            printf("Type new name: ");
            scanf("%d", name);
               products[exists].p_name += name;
                printf("Successfully updated.\n");
        }
}

int display_products() 
{
        int x;
        if(c_p == 0) 
      {
            printf("No products were added\n");
            return;
      }
        printf("Products\n\n");
        for(x = 0; x < c_p; x++) 
      {
        printf("Product ID: %d\n", products[x].p_id);
        printf("Product Name: %s\n", products[x].p_name);
        printf("Quantity: %d\n", products[x].p_quantity);
        printf("Product price: %d\n", products[x].unit_price);
        printf("Product type:%s\n",products[x].p_name);
        printf("\n");
      }
}
```

Comment: First of all please try to create a [mcve] to show us, with emphasis on the *minimal* part, and [edit] your question to show it. Then include a comment on the line where you get the errors. And also include a *full* and *complete* copy-paste (as text!) of the build output.

Comment: Please dont add random text to avoid editor restrictions. Provide details of your issue instead.

Comment: By the way, since `scanf("%d", name);` doesn't result in a warning message from the compiler, you need to enable more warnings. Since you seem to be using an environment which uses GCC or Clang as compiler, add the options `-Wall -Wextra` when building. Then treat all warning messages as errors that must be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to add an integer to a string. This is not allowed in C:

```c
products[exists].p_name += name;
```

Looking at the `change_product` method it seems like maybe you want to update the name field or concatenate it. I think you should do these things:

1. Read all compiler warnings and consider addressing them, They are addressing valid concerns like not declaring your functions first, not returning any `int` value in `add_product`, `display_product` etc which is supposed to return int. Provide a function body for `display_all_products` (Did you mean `display_products()`?)
2. Use a string variable for updating name `char newName[product_limit + 1]` and use library functions from C string library to either concatenate(`strcat`) or copy(`strcpy`) `newName` taken as user input to `products[exists].p_name`:

```c
    char newName[product_limit + 1];

    // ...
    }  else {
        printf("Type new name: ");
        fgets(newName, product_limit + 1, stdin);

        strcpy(products[exists].p_name, newName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't add integer to string.
You have used string functions like strcpy() and should do the same for this.
You have also made other errors :

- declaring int for string(char array)
- wrong return data type
- calling wrong funtion

  I have fixed those errors, do side by side comparison.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>//here
#include<string.h>
#define MAX 100 
#define product_limit 50

//here
void add_product(void);
void change_product(void);
int display_menu(void);
void display_products(void);
int product_exists(int);


typedef struct {
        int p_id;
        char p_name[product_limit + 1];
        int p_quantity; 
        int unit_price; 
        char type_product[50]; 
} product;
int main() 
{ 
    int ok = 1, menu;
    do 
    {
    menu = display_menu();
    if(menu < 1 || menu > 4) 
    {
        printf("Invaid option.\n");
    } 
    else 
    {
        switch(menu)
        {
            case 1:
                add_product();
                break;
            case 2:
                change_product();
                break;
            case 3:
                display_products();//here
                break;
            case 4: 
                exit(0);//here
            }
        }
    } 
    while(ok);
    printf("Exiting Program.\n");
    return 0;
}
int display_menu()
{
    int menu;
    printf("Choose option from below.\n");
    printf("1. Add new product.\n");
    printf("2. Update product.\n");
    printf("3. Display products.\n");
    printf("4. Exit.\n");
    scanf("%d", &menu);
    return menu;
}
product products[MAX];
int c_p = 0;
int product_exists(int id)
{
    int x;
    for(x=0;x<c_p;x++) 
    {
        if(products[x].p_id == id) 
        {
            return x;
        }
    }
        return -1; 
}
void add_product() // here
{
    int price,id,quantity;
    char type[product_limit + 1];
    char name[product_limit + 1];//here
    printf("Product ID: ");
    scanf("%d", &id);
    if(product_exists(id) != -1) 
    {
        printf("ID: %d already exists.\n", id);
        return;
    }
    printf("Enter Product Name: ");
    scanf("%s", name);
    printf("Enter Quantity: ");
    scanf("%d", &quantity);
    printf("Enter Price: ");
    scanf("%d", &price);
    printf("Enter Product Type:");
    scanf("%s",type);
    products[c_p].p_id = id;
    strcpy(products[c_p].p_name, name);
    products[c_p].p_quantity = quantity;
    products[c_p].unit_price = price;
    strcpy(products[c_p].type_product,type);//here
    c_p++;
    printf("Product added Successfully\n");
}
void change_product() //here
{
    int id, exists;
    char z[2];
    char name[product_limit + 1];//here
    printf("Product ID: ");
    scanf("%d", &id);
    exists = product_exists(id);//here
    if(exists == -1) 
    {
        printf("ID: %d not exists.\n", id);
        printf("Type Y to try once more or N back to menu: ");
        scanf("%s", z);
        if(strcmp(z, "Y") == 0) 
        {
            change_product();
        }
    } 
    else 
    {
        printf("Product found successfully\n");
        printf("Product Name: %s\n", products[exists].p_name);
        printf("Type new name: ");
        scanf("%s", &name);//here
        strcpy(products[exists].p_name, name);//here
        printf("Successfully updated.\n");
    }
}

void display_products() //here
{
    int x;
    if(c_p == 0) 
    {
        printf("No products were added\n");
        return;
    }
    printf("Products\n\n");
    for(x = 0; x < c_p; x++) 
    {
    printf("Product ID: %d\n", products[x].p_id);
    printf("Product Name: %s\n", products[x].p_name);
    printf("Quantity: %d\n", products[x].p_quantity);
    printf("Product price: %d\n", products[x].unit_price);
    printf("Product type:%s\n",products[x].type_product);//here
    printf("\n");
    }
}
```